# How do I know which IP address of an Azure App Service to whitelist in Google Cloud SQL

Tags: azure, google-cloud-sql

I have an Azure App Service that needs to communicate first to a Google Cloud SQL database. I already "whitelisted" an IP address (obtained from Custom Domains) of that App Service in Google Cloud SQL db instance. However, the Azure App Service always throws a `db connection timeout`.

I'm assuming that I whitelisted the wrong IP address. I checked the Properties of the Azure App Service and saw some outbound IP addresses. Should I whitelist the outbound IP address too or is their a more correct way to whitelist the Azure App SErvice to be able to communicate with Google Cloud SQL?

Thanks for the help!

**UPDATE**

Solved by whitelisting all outbound IP addresses of the Azure App Service.

Comment: Could you write the solution you found as an answer, please?

Comment: @alextru Sure. I'll post it

Answer (score 1):

This was solved by whitelisting all Outbound IPs of the Azure App Service. In order determine the Outbound IP's of your App Service:

1. Go to your App Service
2. In the Settings (left-side nav), click Properties.
3. Check `Outbound IP addresses` text field and you will see a couple of IP addresses there.

Next,

1. Go to your Google Cloud Console, select a project and proceed to SQL.
2. In SQL, select your instance.
3. Go to Connections
4. Set the `Outbound IP addresses` from Azure App Service in the `Authorized networks` of your GCP Cloud SQL.

Hope this will be a big help to others.

Comment: Do I need to also whitelist the "Additional Outbound IPs" ?